# Windows store app sokets

Tags: c#, sockets, stream, windows-store-apps

i am writing windows store app, that use sockets to send data via tcp protocol.
i put this article as a starting point: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj150599.aspx
but i cant understand some moments:
 1. when server send data to me (client) it is automaticaly "pushed" to DataReader reader ?
 2. are there any event that is called when data recieved, or i can ony manually look for UnconsumedBufferLength property in reader?
 3. does the data sends to server when i call witer.WriteByte(byte)?

Answer (score 0):

There is no event which is raised when there is data available. You have to constantly look whether your input stream contains data- if it does you can read them. To send the data you can use these methods:

```
var writer = new DataWriter(ActiveSocket.OutputStream);
writer.WriteBytes(data);
writer.WriteString();
await writer.StoreAsync();
await writer.FlushAsync();
```

To read the data you only have to call the `Read` method of the `DataReader` class.

Answer (score 0):

If you can possibly use any other protocol (e.g., REST or SignalR), then I recommend you do so. TCP/IP sockets are deliciously low-level (and extremely difficult to get right without a lot of experience).

To answer your question directly, you should always have a read going on the socket. You know that data is received when your read completes.